# How can I track calling code in a SQL Server trace?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'd like to use SQL Server traces to track more context about what code is using the database. I was going to use the "Application Name" property on the connection string. That looks something like the following:

```
object CallingObject; //set elsewhere
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = GetConnectionString();
connectionString.ApplicationName = CallingObject.GetType().ToString();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
{
    // do your thing
}
```

Except that the large variety of resulting connection strings would mean that .net's Connection Pooling is no longer effective.

How can I track calling code in a SQL Trace without losing the benefit of connection pooling?

Comment: I have an idea that might work, but: what are the key things you want to achieve in your trace? (this will tell me whether the idea holds water)

Comment: Hi Marc, I'd like to collect a trace and use that information to attribute x% of db activity to this code and y% of db activity to that code. (Activity being CPU, reads, writes, duration etc...)

Comment: hmmm;  ok - bit of data-mining then. I don't think it is a direct "hit", but for *code-path* profiling (on, say, a per-request basis) we use [mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/), which is useful for finding where time *in a single request* (say) is spent. Less useful in your case, perhaps/

Comment: FWIW, thanks for your attention to this.

Comment: I haven't tested this myself yet, so I'm not submitting as an answer, but wouldn't it be possible to prefix the command with a comment? I.e. something like: string.Format("/*{0}*/\n{1}",CallingObject.GetType().ToString(),myCommand);

Comment: @Anders UP, It's a good idea! Except that we use a lot of stored procedures and for ad-hoc query plan re-use would take a small hit.

Comment: Do you need to know this on an ongoing basis or just initially? If the former, I'd suggest using a profiler such as ANTS or similar on your desktop, run through the use cases and you can easily find which code paths call the stored procedure within about 5 minutes of completing your profiling. If ongoing, there are other tools to do this. Also, is SQL Trace really the tool you want to be doing this? You could just as easily throw some logging in your data access code to also do the same thing and dump it to excel. (e.g. Log(procName, CallStack)

Comment: You could add specific SQL Profiler Trace calls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188662.aspx), manually or using some post processing tool. These traces are displayed nicely in the profiler.

Comment: @Dotnetnate, Thanks, but it's kind of on an ongoing basis. @ Simon, The goal is to add extra information to be available in a trace.

Comment: If it's ongoing, there are tools for that too. DynaTrace, Avicode, etc... are capable of doing this exact thing. If this is an enterprise or public facing application, it's probably worth investing in the tooling - if it's a one off, there are obviously more manual solutions including explicit logging, calling additional stored procedures, etc... all of which have other considerations.

Comment: Hi @dotnetnate, Thanks for your attention to this issue. sql profiler is the tool I want to do this. It has information like duration, cpu, reads, writes used by the database server which is not accessible from client side profilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're using SQL Server, and as long as you have (or can have) centralized connection-creation logic, you can use the `CONTEXT_INFO` feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx

We do something like this to track DB connections in a multi-user server-side application. Every time a new DB connection is created (reused from connection pooling, really, but "created" in ADODB/ADO.Net code):

```
DECLARE @ContextInfoBinary binary(128); 
SET @ContextInfoBinary = Convert(Binary(128), 'XX' + Replicate(Char(0), 36) + 'Up to 90 characters of connection info - username, page, action, etc') 
SET CONTEXT_INFO @ContextInfoBinary
```

Later, when you want to "track" the connections, you can convert the specified range of the context-info back to VarChar content:

```
SELECT RTRIM(hostname) AS hostname
    , hostprocess
    , RTRIM(program_name) AS program_name
    , CASE 
        WHEN SubString(Context_Info, 1, 2) = 0x5858
            THEN Replace(Convert(VarChar(90), SubString(Context_Info, 39, 90)), CHAR(0), '')
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
        END AS ExtendedConnectionDescription
    --More stuff here, depending on what you're looking for
FROM master.sys.sysprocesses
```

Some considerations:

- We moved to this concept specifically because of connection-pooling issues with the Application Name feature. It's important to us to be able to track blocking causes down to specific users and processes, at any given point in time.
- This adds a DB command to be executed for *every* connection created - this may or may not represent significant overhead, depending on your application design
- This sample uses VarChar (up to 90 characters); if you need to track NVarChar(extended character) data, your space drops to 45 characters
- In this example we're leaving 36 bytes that could be used for some other purpose, eg for preventing triggers from executing for some connections.
- You can output the value to a trace explicitly using `sp_trace_generateevent`, as outlined in this related question: [How do you access the Context_Info() variable in SQL2005 Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049656/how-do-you-access-the-context-info-variable-in-sql2005-profiler)

---

UPDATE:

Only after re-reading your question did I realize you seem to be  explicitly looking to add info to Traces only, and not so much for ad-hoc analysis of your current connections (which is more what I associated the use of "Application Name" with, sorry); the only useful approach I've seen specifically is the `sp_trace_generateevent` call. If you're going to do this, I'd advise you to **also** add the connection_info, as it won't cost you any more (you alsready have the db round-trip for `sp_trace_generateevent`) and will definitely help you with other types of analysis later on.

Comment: There are also security ramifications of this procedure which you may or may not want to give arbitrary applications. An additional factor to consider.

Comment: This will do! Thanks Tao. There's some post-processing to match the custom event (UserConfigurable:1) with the statistics of the same process. But I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try these tools out:

Redgate Performance Profiler:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

dotTrace:
http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html

Visual Studio Performance Profiler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx

Comment: I'd like to collect the information from that database server side. While these are client side traces.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have the trace output to a database table (preferably on a different machine/instance than the trace is running on)?  That way you can query the trace table based off your parameters, see what operations are soaking up all the CPU %, see the command text for it, etc.

Comment: Hmmm that's what I plan to do. Except this doesn't address the tricky part of figuring out which bit of code in the application is calling/invoking each query/sproc

Comment: First off, you should minimize the amount of ad hoc queries you construct and call from code.  Your data access layer should me making stored proc calls 95% of the time.  In the trace you'll be able to see which stored proc or query is being run.  But you want to see which bit of code is calling it???  I'm sure you'd be able to hone in on that really quickly, given the command text of the trace.

Comment: Hi Surfer, thanks for spending time on this question. The command text of the trace will tell me the sql that is getting run, not the C# class or assembly that is making the call. (See the code sample in the question for the kind of information I'm trying to capture).

Comment: I think I didn't make something clear in the question. I should add that we have several products --> several data access layers, which call overlapping stored procedures... That's what I'm trying to sort out.