# Changing Application Name on SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, oledb, ado

Can the Application Name passed to SQL Server (via the ADO Connection string) be changed once the connection is open without closing and re-opening the connection?

In particular, I'm using ADO, not ADO.NET, and the SQLOLEDB.1 OLE DB Provider.

We embed the session information in the Application Name, to help us identify the connection specific to a user's session.  This primarily helps when troubleshooting bad queries or performance issues.

We currently do not use a connection pool for our ADO connections.  I'm considering implementing a connection pool, but would like to update the Application Name when a connection is removed from the pool, so that we have accurate session information in the Application Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would doubt that you can alter any attribute of a connection string after the connection has been created (in the pool or not). Connections are [assigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to pools based on the value of the connection string itself, so if you could change the application name after the connection has been picked from the pool, it would essentially belong to a differnt pool from that point on, which would likely mess up connection pool management internally.

Furthermore, the application name is used as (I think you already know that as you said you're trying to use it for performance and troubleshooting reasons) to populate the `program_name` column of `sys.dm_exec_sessions`. So unless there is a way that this value can change for an existig connection, I think there is no way to do it from ADO.NET either.

Having that said, I use the application name for the same purpose. I just "hardcode" the application name to some symbolic string (e.g. "myapp-client") and that has always been sufficient to figure the exact calling application on a crowed server (at least together with the `host_process_id` column of `sys.dm_exec_sessions`).

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Sadly, I did not realize ADO had its own connection pooling (I thought that arrived with ADO.NET).  So I've spent some time investigating and considering the options.  Our architecture is such that once a user receives an ADO connection, that connection is left open (in our server) until the user logs out.  Changing the architecture to allow ADO to pool the connections isn't an easy option.  My thought all along was to create my own connection pool, which is still what I'm planning.

Comment: That said, we're going to add the ability to turn on or off the connection pool while the server is running.  If we need to troubleshoot an issue and need to trace a user's database activity, we'll turn off the connection pool and new connections will have the user's name in sysprocesses.program_name.  When users login, their connection will be configured based on whether the connection pool is currently enabled.  Turning it on/off will not modify the behavior of existing connections.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use SQL CONTEXT_INFO, 128 bytes available per connection, which can be changed at runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I just now noticed your answer, so my apologies for the late response.  Very interesting suggestion.  Not particularly easy to access via SQL Profiler, and that's the main purpose I'm trying to accomplish (when troubleshooting a performance issue).  But it should be possible, based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049656/how-do-you-access-the-context-info-variable-in-sql2005-profiler)